# Auto Layout - effect of adding several constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout

I look over [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH13-SW1) article, and i have a question.

Consider following constraints on text field object:

```
First Name Text Field.Top >= Top Layout Guide.Bottom + 20.0
First Name Text Field.Top = Top Layout Guide.Bottom + 20.0 (Priority 249)
```

I'm confused. If i add greater then or equal constraint, isnt that mean that i already say - set this distance greater then or equal 20? What the point to add second constraint - `First Name Text Field.Top = Top Layout Guide.Bottom + 20.0 (Priority 249)`. It also have lowered priority, so i suppose, it will never evaluated, because first constraint -  `First Name Text Field.Top >= Top Layout Guide.Bottom + 20.0` have greater priority.

Could someone explain that logic to me? Is there any point to add 2 constraint with different priorities? Any point to add greater-then-or-equal constraint and constraint, that equal to same value (20 in case)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *greater than or equal* constraint is ambiguous by its very nature.  You have told *Auto Layout* to make the distance between your first name text field and the top layout guide's bottom *at least* `20`.  Note that `20`, `30`, and `50` would all satisfy that constraint.

By adding the second constraint, you tell *Auto Layout* that you'd prefer it to be `20`.  By making the priority `249` you tell *Auto Layout* that this request is *low* (priorities go to `1000`) and should be broken first if it needs to break a constraint to make things work.

So, using these 2 constraints, *Auto Layout* will make the distance `20` if it can.  If not, it will use a value greater than `20`.

Comment: thanks, you mean constraint with lower priority will try to evaluate first?

Comment: No.  Constraints with a higher priority are satisfied first.  Auto Layout will try to satisfy all of the constraints.  If that is impossible, it will modify or ignore the lower priority constraints first.

Comment: but greater then or equal to contain - equal to.. i mean, it is already equal to second constraint. if it was greater then or equal 21, for example, there will be difference.

Comment: `>= 20` doesn't tell *Auto Layout* whether it should use `20`, `30`, or `50`.  They all are `>= 20`.  By adding the second constraint `== 20 (priority 249)` you say I'd really prefer you choose `20` *if you can*.  If other constraints make that impossible, then ignore this request for `== 20`.

Comment: thanks for explanation, but could you explain please order. First, it will try to use >= 20, and only in case it is impossible it will use == 20?

Comment: *Auto Layout* starts out to attempt to satisfy all of the constraints.  So if `20` works, then both constraints `>= 20` and `== 20` are satisfied.  If for some reason (because of other constraints) `20` isn't  possible, then *Auto Layout* will break the lowest priority constraints *first* to make everything work. `249` is a *low* priority with `1000` being the highest.   So if `20` won't work, it will use another number.  Because you have indicated that `20` is desired, it will use the value closest to `20` to satisfy the `>=` constraint.

Comment: thanks, you mean 249 is higher priority then >= ? Im a bit confused.

Comment: Imagine you told a friend to "pick a number greater than or equal to 20".  This is a demand, priority 1000, you won't let them go until they answer.  And they say `50`.  Now if you say "pick any number greater than or equal to 20, but it would make my Mom happy if you chose `20`.  The second part isn't a demand (priority 249) but your friend would probably say `20` because it can satisfy both parts of your request.  They are still free to say "21. I hate the number 20" and they would have satisfied your required part `>= 20` while ignoring your low priority optional part `== 20`.

Comment: thanks for explanation, if i understand correct, in case when it possible Auto Layout try to satisfy 2 constraints, and if it can't, it simply broke lowest priority constraint ( == 20) and just satfisfy one with >= ?

Comment: Right.  And if it has to break `== 20` it will get as close to it as it can.

Comment: i want to ask a quick question - if i dont specific another, any constraint is set with priority of 1000?

Comment: If you explicitly create a constraint in code, then its priority defaults to `1000`.  It can be set to another number like `249` like this: `myConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 249)`.